# jQuery version 1.5 - ajax - <script> tag timestamp problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timestamp, jquery-1.5

If I load some content with ajax (jQuery) which has a script tag in it, jQuery 1.5 adds the timestamp to the script tag src url. See example bellow.

Example:
content what I load with ajax:

```
<div>text1</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/abc-xyz.js?r=1.1"></script>
```

This is the src url from where it loads the script code after I insert the previous content to the page:

```
.../js/abc-xyz.js?r=1.1&_=1297892228466
```

Does anybody knows why this happening?
It happens only with jQuery 1.5. It doesn't happen with jQuery 1.4.4.

Code Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: content.html,
    type: 'GET',
    data: someDataObject,
    success: function(data) {
        // some code here

    },
    error: function(data) {
        // some code here
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: If i have to take a wild gess i would say it adds the get parameter to prevent the js file from loading from cache. Cant think of any other reason atm. But this should not break any functionality.

Comment: Could you show your Javascript?

Comment: I added JavaScript code example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See bellow the answer what I got back from jQuery team.
Ticket #8298: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8298

Answer:

After checking your report and your code samples I come to the conclusion that this isn't a bug. I also made [this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jitter/kdxGp/) jQuery 1.4+ (until 1.5) had a bug which caused the cache option not to default to false for script requests. This bug (see [#7578](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7578)) has been fixed in 1.5 .
Now what you might know or not know is, that jQuery does special-handle script tags when doing DOM manipulations (to prevent certain errors in IE). It filters them out and requests them via ajax. This explains why even a "normal" inline script tag suddenly is requested with additional url parameters.
There are ways to work around this if it has unwanted side effects for you.

1. use `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true })` when appropriate
2. use a  [prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/) for script requests and e.g. check for urls where you don't want 
   the random parameter to be added and set cache: true in the prefilter for those
3. in e.g. the success call back handle the script tags yourself by doing something along these..

..lines:

```
var elems = $(htmlwithscripttags);
elems.filter("script") //now do whatever with the scripts
elems.filter(":not(script)").appendTo("body"); //e.g.
```

Comment: `2` works well for me:
    `$.ajaxPrefilter('script', function(options) {
        options.cache = true;
    });`

Answer (score 7):

Michael is correct in **[his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022557/jquery-version-1-5-ajax-script-tag-timestamp-problem#comment-5616648)**, and if you want to disable it, use:
`cache: true` in the ajax request. To enable, use `cache: false` (which I believe is default).

**To disable the timestamp:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: content.html,
    cache: true,
    type: 'GET',
    data: someDataObject,
    success: function(data) {
        // some code here

    },
    error: function(data) {
        // some code here
    }
});
```

Comment: I know how to control caching. My problem is that ads the timestampt to the script src url which was loaded with ajax.

Comment: This issue in our project at work was caused by `$.ajaxSetup({cache:false})` being added to a plugin that was being called.

Comment: This approach isn't the best, because $.ajaxSetup is valid for all requests.