# Unwanted underscore and unix timestamp appearing after javascript include

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, include, numbers

On pages that have been loaded using jquery's load function, all javascript files included have an argument '_' with a value equal to the current unix timestamp plus 3 extra numbers when they are loaded.

E.g., If I include "file.js", the actual file that gets included will be "file.js?_=1378360893522".

It is preventing the javascript files from caching, is there any way to stop this behaviour?

**Edit:** As requested here is the relevant code:

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='new-page'></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#new-page').load("another-page.html");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

another-page.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/another-js-file.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "another-js-file.js" is loaded as "another-js-file.js?_=1378425747710"

**Second edit:** This was answered. For those reading this I changed my load call to be something more like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "another-page.html",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data){
        $("#new-page").html(data);
    }
});
```

Some people stated that certain plugins may set cache to be false via ajaxSetup, so it might be necessary to use this before an ajax call you want cached:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to contain an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is well documented and a solution can be taken from:

[jQuery version 1.5 - ajax - <script> tag timestamp problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022557/jquery-version-1-5-ajax-script-tag-timestamp-problem)

The solution involves using the `cache` option in the jQuery AJAX call.

Comment: This works, thanks. I've updated my question to contain an answer specific to this question.