# How to get rid of forcefully added underscore with timestamp

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project with MVC5 and ran into an issue of MVC trying to "help" me, i think. What i'm doing is trying to tidy up views by extracting their javascript without fiddling around with the bundle config.

Messing around with generic loading in the bundle folder would be an option but i'd rather avoid that.

So here's my code, which is working:

```
    public static string GetControllerName(this ControllerBase controller)
    {
        var name = controller.GetType().Name;
        if (name.ToLower().EndsWith("controller"))
            return name.Substring(0, name.Length - 10);
        return name;
    }

    public static IHtmlString LoadViewScripts(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        var view = helper.ViewContext.View as RazorView;
        if (view != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.ViewPath))
        {
            var controllerName = helper.ViewContext.Controller.GetControllerName();
            var vPath = string.Format("~/Scripts/View/{0}/{1}.js", controllerName, Path.GetFileName(view.ViewPath));

            var realPath = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(vPath);
            if (File.Exists(realPath))
            {
                var urlPath = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(vPath, helper.ViewContext.HttpContext);
                var lwrite = File.GetLastWriteTime(realPath);

                return new HtmlString(string.Format("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='{0}?v={1}'></script>", urlPath, lwrite.Ticks));
            }
        }

        return new HtmlString(string.Empty);
    }
```

Result i am passing to src attribute:

```
http://localhost/AppName/Scripts/View/Map/SelectSite.cshtml.js?v=635569414679160391
```

What i am getting (network view of firefox):

```
http://localhost/AppName/Scripts/View/Map/SelectSite.cshtml.js?v=635569414679160391&_=1421342715176
```

What i am expecting (network view of firefox):

```
http://localhost/AppName/Scripts/View/Map/SelectSite.cshtml.js?v=635569414679160391
```

Does anyone know how to stop MVC from "helping" me cache/refresh things in this particular case?

Comment: Are you perhaps passing the HTML into jQuery via ajax? I know jQuery adds that to prevent caching.

Comment: Would lwrite.Ticks.ToString().SubString(0, 18) work to cut off the underscore and anything after it?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan not directly. This method is called in the corresponding view like @Html.LoadViewScripts(). The view itself is loaded via ajax however (Using kendoUI window here, no property regarding caching) and contains an underscore as well, which is not my intention either.

Comment: @dkiefer no. that's the thing which is puzzling me so much. the string within "urlPath" is exactely what i want. but somehow it's beeing modified.

Comment: looks like a component error of the kendo component. i'll add the solution here once telerik gave the info on how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So it turns out there was 2 reasons why it wasnt working for me.

1. The kendo property to disable caching which is enabled by default wasn't in the api. Calling it like this fixed my window issue.

   ```
   content: {
    url: targetUrlSiteSelect,
    cache : true
   }
   ```
2. My additional script tag still contained that the underscore element. I later on found that solution contained within a comment here: 
   [jQuery version 1.5 - ajax - <script> tag timestamp problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022557/jquery-version-1-5-ajax-script-tag-timestamp-problem)

Comment by Blaise:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter('script', function(options) { options.cache = true; });
```